# Need to backup the data but it's not working in Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to backup the data in Airflow but it's not giving any error and also I am unable to backup the data because it's getting skipped. The code which I have written is :-

```
import os
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_gcs import (
BigQueryToGCSOperator,
)
from composer_plugins import get_list_to_backup
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowFailException, AirflowSkipException
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

"""the function validates if the schedule_day parameter is a valid day to execute the task schedule_day is a number and corresponds to day of the week
1 - Monday
2 - Tuesday
3 - Wednesday
4 - Thursday
5 - Friday
6 - Saturday
7 - Sunday """
def _check_valid_day(**kwargs):
    today = datetime.today()
    if today.isoweekday()==kwargs["schedule_day"]:
        return True
    else:
     raise AirflowSkipException("does not correspond to the backup day")

today = datetime.today()
today_str = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#start_date = get_next_weekday(today_str, 5)  # 5 = Saturday
start_date = datetime(2022, 5, 2)
dag_id = "data_bq_weekly_backups_dag"

event_collection_project_id = os.environ["EVENT_COLLECTION_PROJECT_ID"]
tables_to_backup = os.environ["TABLES_TO_BACKUP"]
destination_bucket = os.environ["WEEKLY_BQ_BACKUP_BUCKET"]
schedule_day =os.environ["BACKUP_SCHEDULE_DAY"]

default_dag_args = {
# Setting start date for next Saturday in order to maintain the scheduler
# in a consistent state
"start_date": start_date,
# To email on failure or retry set 'email' arg to your email and enable
# emailing here.
"email_on_failure": False,
"email_on_retry": False,
# If a task fails, retry it once after waiting at least what's specified in retry_delay
"retries": 1,
"retry_delay": timedelta(seconds=10),
"project_id": event_collection_project_id,
"schedule_interval": "0 2 * * *",
}


tables_to_backup_list = get_list_to_backup(tables_to_backup)

with DAG(dag_id=dag_id, default_args=default_dag_args,catchup=False) as dag:

check_valid_day = PythonOperator(
    task_id='check_valid_day',
    python_callable=_check_valid_day,
    op_kwargs={
            "schedule_day": schedule_day
            },
    )
task_dict = dict()

for table_to_backup in tables_to_backup_list:
    dataset = table_to_backup.split(".")[0]
    table = table_to_backup.split(".")[1]
    task_name = f"{dataset}_{table}_table_weekly_backup"
    task_dict[task_name] = BigQueryToGCSOperator(
        task_id=task_name,
        trigger_rule="all_success",
        dag=dag,
        source_project_dataset_table=table_to_backup,
        destination_cloud_storage_uris=[
            f"gs://{destination_bucket}/{dataset}/{table}/{today.year}/{today.month}/{today.day}/{table}-*.avro"
        ],
        export_format="AVRO",  # OPTIONS: AVRO, CSV, JSON
        compression="NONE",  # OPTIONS: NONE, DEFLATE, GZIP, SNAPPY
        labels=None,
    )
    check_valid_day >>  task_dict[task_name]
```

When I am executing this DAG, there is no error but it's skipping everything :-
[Airflow DAG TREE VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9ZvO.png)
BACKUP_SCHEDULE_DAY=3 is set in environment variable file. I don't know what's wrong in this and why it's not working

Comment: Why don't you use `BranchDayOfWeekOperator` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code I was able to reproduce your issue. See run history below:

[image]

NOTE: Prior to running your code, I hardcoded values like your environment variables and `tables_to_backup_list` to make it work on my environment.

The main problem is in `_check_valid_day()`. When this line is executed `if today.isoweekday()==kwargs["schedule_day"]` it is always **false** because they have a data type mismatch.

```
print(today.isoweekday()) # <class 'int'>
print(kwargs["schedule_day"]) # <class 'str'>
```

The fix is to make their data types match. Fix below is to convert `kwargs["schedule_day"]` to **type int**:

```
def _check_valid_day(**kwargs):
    today = datetime.today()
    if today.isoweekday() == int(kwargs["schedule_day"]): #convert to int
        print("inside the if statement")
        return True
    else:
        raise AirflowSkipException("does not correspond to the backup day")
```

Graph view:

[image]

`check_valid_day` Logs:

[image]

Comment: I have made the changes which you told but it's still skipping everything and not going in If statement and returning "doesn't correspond to the backup day",may be because of scheduled day. For the testing purpose, is that possible if I can I  hardcode any value in DAG, so that it can execute? If yes, what I can hardcode, so that it can execute? The other thing which I wanted to understand, what is datetime(2022, 5, 2) corresponds to ?

Comment: @Priya Yes most probably if your scheduled day is not equal to the iso week day it will skip your tasks. Your dag will work if you satisfy the condition in your `_check_valid_day()` by possibly hardcoding a value for schedule day or comment it out in the meantime and just retain your `task_dict[task_name]` for the sake of testing your dag. `datetime(2022, 5, 2)` is supposed to be your `start_date` I believe. You can read through [airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html) to understand it better or create a new question about your `start_date`